# Good alternative to make a sql-like language transpiler

Tags: compiler-construction, dsl, transpiler

I need to make a DSL which output a SQL-like language. First, I thought in roll my own transpiler using a recursive descent parser + a simple code generation approach. But as the DSL language is really simple and so is the output language, I realized I would try find a less-time and energy, consuming approach where I don't reinvent the wheel, like a more powerful version of C pre-processor. First came on mind was m4, I've had only hear about before, never used it so far. I'm reading some tutorials/documentations but I still unsure if I can accomplish my goal with this tool. 
For example I want turn:

```
display a,b,c if a.substring(0, 3) == b.substring(0, 3) and (c + 8 > 20 || c == 0)
```

Would translate into something like that:

```
SELECT A, B, C from tbl where substring(A, 0, 3) = substring(B, 0, 3) and (c + 8 > 20 or c = 0)
```

So I what's a good way to accomplish this? keep learning [`M4`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4_%28computer_language%29) or should I try another tool (if so, which one) or I'm better off doing my own compiler implementation?

Comment: If your DSL trivially translates to some other language, it isn't adding a lot of value; why not just write whatever you were going to write in that language?   If the translation isn't trivial, then choosing a trivial "transpiler" framework will not add much to implementing the translation and thus building your transpiler will be hard.   I think what you will discover is that you can't avoid a parser (thus M4 isn't an answer) and that just a parser isn't enough.  See http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html

Answer (score 2):

> I need to make a DSL

I'll work on the assumption that you need to create a DSL. While a lot of problems look like a DSL would help quite often a good understanding of another language would actually be more beneficial.

> like a more powerful version of C pre-processor.

The C preprocessor is considered by many and I'm one of those many a non trivial program, `developing something more powerful` would, at least to me, constitute a work of fine art.

Developing a recursive descent parser is also non trivial for any non trivial input. It's easy to understand but handling all cases/productions etc becomes quite a bit of work. It would be easier but still non trivial if you used something like ANTLR to define your grammar and then use it to generate the parser.

DSL does not imply simple it implies simpler, C is simpler than C++ to parse and Scheme is simpler than C to parse but writing a good scheme parser that has no bugs is going to take [some effort](http://norvig.com/lispy.html) and scheme is one of the simplest.

Comment: OP proposed to use m4 (he doesn't need to build it) which is at least as powerful as the C preprocessor.  But a macro processor is not a great foundation for a DSL compiler.   Building a parser actually is techically easy ("no hard problemds to solve") but the least of OP's troubles when it comes to building a translator.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for building a proper external DSLs. In this way you can validate the code and having things like typesystem rules.

Would your language be independent or would it need to interoperate with other languages (e.g., Java or C)? Would you need editor support?

A parser can be easily written with ANTLR. As Ira Baxter pointed out there are other aspects to consider and the effort needed really to implement those other things depend on your experience in the field.